# Can using a math interpreter be potentially dangerous?

Tags: security, math, interpreter

I want the user to be able to write their own math functions in my program. And these functions could possibly be shared with someone else, and run natively on their machine. Algebra is Turing complete. Does it mean I should warn users of my program about potential danger of running math? Sorry if this is a silly question :)

Edit:
I am making a simple diary, but the entries have dynamically calculated properties. I am thinking of using bc for running the user defined functions. It's rather easy to fix things for user if the expression does not end since they can modify the expression outside of the program. But let's say user A sends user B their diary. Should I warn user B that it's not safe to open their diary?

Comment: Your question is rather vague, but yes, there are potential issues. For example, if you asked Python to calculate `10**(10**10)`, it would most likely grind to a halt, possibly necessitating a system reset.

Comment: @r3mainer If by "system reset" you mean the termination of the program, then it's not critical in my case. To be more precise, well, I am making a simple diary, but the entries have dynamically calculated properties. I am thinking of using `bc` for running the user defined functions. It's rather easy to fix things for user if the expression does not end since they can modify the expression outside of the program. But let's say user A sends user B their diary. Should I warn user B that it's not safe to open their diary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can have a Turing-complete language with recursion, but limit the stack size and run time (to kill the busy beavers) for each user script. If it's implemented as some kind of a VM it'll be very easy to do. You can also have a total functional language to ensure termination (but that won't solve the busy beavers problem).

Comment: I clarified the question a little bit. Is halting the most algebra could do to user's system? If it's the case, I will only warn the user before opening a new unknown diary.

Comment: @rasuru unless you expose any dangerous side-effect functions and as long as your implementation is secure, you're safe. All a sandboxed computation can do is consume RAM and CPU time. You can hard limit both.